# Are there any issues with assigning a new CancellationTokenSource(); to a variable more than once?

Tags: c#

Can someone clarify for me.  If I have a variable of type CancellationTokenSource and it already has been assigned to like this:

```
public CancellationTokenSource tokenSource2;

tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then would there be any problem if later in my code I did this:

```
tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

What is confusing me is that there is a way of disposing of the CancellationTokenSource.

Should I dispose of it before assigning to it again?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with reusing a `CancellationTokenSource`, it's very common.

[Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

> The CancellationTokenSource class implements the IDisposable
> interface. You should be sure to call the
> CancellationTokenSource.Dispose method when you have finished using
> the cancellation token source to free any unmanaged resources it
> holds.

So you could do as such:

```
tokenSource2?.Dispose();
tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource
```

There are some caveats though

> If you call Dispose while the callback is running, and you hold a lock
> that the callback is waiting on, your program can deadlock. After
> Dispose returns, you can free any resources required by the callback.

Also see this

[How to: Listen for Multiple Cancellation Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests)

Actually I'd suggest you read the whole page [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Comment: "If you call Dispose while the callback is running" < so would an even safer thing be to first do a cancel just to be sure?

Comment: @Alan2 if you have tasks running using the supplied token any you are replacing the cancellation source id be suspicious